# iOS: Remove empty space at the top of webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift3, ios10

I am trying to delete empty space from the top of my webView:

[image]

This is the solution:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();
    webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero;
}
```

The solution is from this question: [iOS WebView blank gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883961/ios-webview-blank-gap)

But for me the problem still exists.  I've also tried this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();
    mainWebView.scrollView.contentInset.top = UIEdgeInsets.zero.top;
}
```

And this:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

But the annoying white space is still there. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465275/ios-webview-leaves-empty-space-before-html-content

Comment: @MarcusLeon Leon yes, i have already tried this, but the problem is still there

Comment: have you checked if the html being displayed in webview contains blank white spacing?

Comment: Yes, there is no white space in html

Comment: @coldembrace, did you get any solution for this? Please post here the solution. It can be helpful to others.